# Radiobutton inside multiple Panel

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

There's 3 radiobutton that i needed to place inside 3 panel which I would then hide depending on the user log in. The problem now is when all of the radiobutton is visible. I couldn't let the user just tick one. I tried Groupname attribute but found no luck.

```
                                              <td>
                                                  <asp:Panel ID="Panel100" runat="server" Visible="True" >
                                                      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="cpem13" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Font-Size="X-Small" Height="18px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="74px" GroupName="B1" >
                                                          <asp:ListItem Text="PDA/PPN" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                                                      </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                                  </asp:Panel> 
                                              </td>
                                              <td>
                                                  <asp:Panel ID="Panel102" runat="server" Visible="True" >
                                                      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Height="18px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="80px" Font-Size="X-Small" GroupName="B1">
                                                          <asp:ListItem Text="PPP/PPW" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                                      </asp:RadioButtonList> 
                                                  </asp:Panel> </td>
                                              <td>
                                                  <asp:Panel ID="Panel103" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="68px" >
                                                      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Height="16px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="218px" Font-Size="X-Small" GroupName="B1">
                                                            <asp:ListItem Text="PAE" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        </asp:RadioButtonList> 
                                                  </asp:Panel> </td>
```

Comment: in your question you are saying that you need radio button in one panel.. but you are using 3 panels. Make it one and give group name

Comment: @AnoopLL Edited to 3 panels. Thanks ! Just to be clear I needed it to be 3 multiple panels. Each having its own asp:ListItem

Comment: @idwell please checkmy answer.it works for me..

Answer (score 1):

```
  <td>
        <asp:panel id="Panel100" runat="server" visible="True">
            <asp:RadioButtonList AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"  CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Font-Size="X-Small" Height="18px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="74px"  >
                <asp:ListItem Text="PDA/PPN" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </asp:panel>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:panel id="Panel102" runat="server" visible="True">
            <asp:RadioButtonList AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="RadioButtonList2_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="RadioButtonList2"  runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Height="18px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="80px" Font-Size="X-Small" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="PPP/PPW" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList> 
        </asp:panel>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:panel id="Panel103" runat="server" visible="True" width="68px">
            <asp:RadioButtonList AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList3_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="RadioButtonList3"  runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Height="16px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="218px" Font-Size="X-Small">
                <asp:ListItem Text="PAE" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList> 
        </asp:panel>
    </td>
```

and in code behind

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex = -1;
        RadioButtonList3.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }
    protected void RadioButtonList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        RadioButtonList3.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
    protected void RadioButtonList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

you can use "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event to achive this